# send and recv using threading python does not work

Tags: python, multithreading, udp

I am writing a program where we can send and receive data but at server side it starts to send message and receives the data too. But at client side it says error assigning to that port. So what port do i need to assign and try to do for two way communication using threads? Please post your ideas and solution as i am new to threading concept.

Thanks

client side: output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/new/ref.py", line 61, in <module>
    send = Sending('username', '192.168.1.27', 8000, 1500)
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/new/ref.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.sock = self.create_socket()
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/new/ref.py", line 17, in create_socket
    sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
running

Process finished with exit code 1
```

client side program:

```
import socket
import threading
import logging
import time


class Sending():
    def __init__(self, name, tHost, tPort, target):
        self.name = name
        self.host = tHost
        self.port = tPort
        self.target_port = target
        self.sock = self.create_socket()

    def create_socket(self):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        return sock

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def send_loop(self):
        while True:
            logging.debug('Starting send run')
            message = input('Enter message: ')
            data = bytearray()
            data.extend(message.encode('utf-8'))
            self.sock.sendto(bytearray(data), (self.host, self.target_port))

    def run(self):
        th2 = threading.Thread(name='send', target=self.send_loop)
        th2.start()


class Receiving():
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def create_socket(self):
        logging.debug('Starting socket')
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        print ('socket ready')
        time.sleep(5)
        while True:
            data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1500)
            print('gyg' + data.decode('utf-8') + str(addr))

    def run(self):
        th1 = threading.Thread(name='rec', target=self.create_socket)
        print("Made it here")
        th1.daemon = True
        th1.start()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('running')
    rec = Receiving('192.168.1.27', 1485)
    send = Sending('username', '192.168.1.27', 8000, 1500)
    rec.run()
    send.run()
```

server side :

```
import threading
from threading import Thread
import socket
from socket import *
import time
import os
import re
import struct
import socket
import threading
import logging
import time


class Sending():
    def __init__(self, name, tHost, tPort, target):
        self.name = name
        self.host = tHost
        self.port = tPort
        self.target_port = target
        self.sock = self.create_socket()

    def create_socket(self):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        return sock

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def send_loop(self):
        while True:
            logging.debug('Starting send run')
            message = input('Enter message: ')
            data = bytearray()
            data.extend(message.encode('utf-8'))
            self.sock.sendto(bytearray(data), (self.host, self.target_port))

    def run(self):
        th2 = threading.Thread(name='send',target=self.send_loop)
        th2.start()


class Receiving():
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def create_socket(self):
        logging.debug('Starting socket')
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        print ('socket ready')
        time.sleep(5)
        while True:
            data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1500)
            print('ggg:' + data.decode('utf-8') + str(addr))

    def run(self):
        th1 = threading.Thread(name='rec', target=self.create_socket)
        print("Made it here")
        th1.daemon = True
        th1.start()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('running')
    rec = Receiving('192.168.1.27', 8000)
    send = Sending('username', '192.168.1.27', 1435, 1024)
    rec.run()
    send.run()
```